# Httpd Access error in installing joomla template

Tags: httpd

I am installing templates in joomla then i am getting this Alert in fedora 17 . How can i provide access to httpd to create the directory or files .

```
SELinux is preventing /usr/sbin/httpd from write access on the directory templates.

    *****  Plugin httpd_write_content (92.2 confidence) suggests  ****************

    If you want to allow httpd to have write access on the templates directory
    Then you need to change the label on 'templates'
    Do
    # semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t 'templates'
    # restorecon -v 'templates'

    *****  Plugin catchall_boolean (7.83 confidence) suggests  *******************

    If you want to httpd_unified
    Then you must tell SELinux about this by enabling the 'httpd_unified' boolean.You can read 'httpd_selinux' man page for more details.
    Do
    setsebool -P httpd_unified 1

    *****  Plugin catchall (1.41 confidence) suggests  ***************************

    If you believe that httpd should be allowed write access on the templates directory by default.
    Then you should report this as a bug.
    You can generate a local policy module to allow this access.
    Do
    allow this access for now by executing:
    # grep httpd /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow -M mypol
    # semodule -i mypol.pp

    Additional Information:
    Source Context                system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
    Target Context                unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0
    Target Objects                templates [ dir ]
    Source                        httpd
    Source Path                   /usr/sbin/httpd
    Port                          <Unknown>
    Host                          amsick
    Source RPM Packages           httpd-2.2.22-4.fc17.x86_64
    Target RPM Packages           
    Policy RPM                    selinux-policy-3.10.0-145.fc17.noarch
    Selinux Enabled               True
    Policy Type                   targeted
    Enforcing Mode                Enforcing
    Host Name                     amsick
    Platform                      Linux amsick 3.5.1-1.fc17.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Aug 9
                                  17:50:43 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64
    Alert Count                   1
    First Seen                    Wed 10 Oct 2012 05:41:43 PM IST
    Last Seen                     Wed 10 Oct 2012 05:41:43 PM IST
    Local ID                      53cfb03d-f93f-43c0-af17-a4dd0b02286c

    Raw Audit Messages
    type=AVC msg=audit(1349871103.424:79): avc:  denied  { write } for  pid=858 comm="httpd" name="templates" dev="dm-1" ino=531647 scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 tclass=dir


    type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1349871103.424:79): arch=x86_64 syscall=mkdir success=no exit=EACCES a0=7fb60b3dd8e0 a1=1ed a2=8 a3=7fff4bfd0b08 items=0 ppid=854 pid=858 auid=4294967295 uid=48 gid=48 euid=48 suid=48 fsuid=48 egid=48 sgid=48 fsgid=48 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm=httpd exe=/usr/sbin/httpd subj=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 key=(null)

    Hash: httpd,httpd_t,httpd_sys_content_t,dir,write

    audit2allow

    #============= httpd_t ==============
    #!!!! This avc can be allowed using the boolean 'httpd_unified'

    allow httpd_t httpd_sys_content_t:dir write;

    audit2allow -R

    #============= httpd_t ==============
    #!!!! This avc can be allowed using the boolean 'httpd_unified'

    allow httpd_t httpd_sys_content_t:dir write;
```

Answer (score 1):

It tells you right in the message how to fix it. It believe with 93 percent certainty that you want to label the content properly which would be these two commands.

semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t 'templates'

restorecon -v 'templates'

Comment: but the above given commands are not working